# If $X$ is a random variable, would f(X) and X have a correlation of 1?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, correlation

If $X$ is a random, would $f(X)$ and $X$ have a correlation of 1?

Comment: Not, for example, $X$ and $-X$.

Comment: Or, $X$ uniform on $[-1,1]$ versus $X^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your unspecified $f$ can transform $X$ in any way it chooses.

The only way $f(X)$ and $X$ have a (Pearson) correlation of $1$ is when
$f(X)=aX+b$ where $a>0$ and $b$ are constants i.e. a linear relationship (with positive slope).